# How to write an "all these numbers are different" condition in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement

OK, I have this problem to solve but I can’t program it in Java correctly. See the picture below, you’ll see a 6 pointed star were every point and intersection of lines is a letter.

[image]

The assignment is to position the numbers 1 to 12 in such a way that the sum of all lines of four balls is 26 and the sum of all the 6 points of the star is 26 as well. 
This comes down to:

- (A+C+F+H==26)
- (A+D+G+K==26)
- (B+C+D+E==26)
- (B+F+I+L==26)
- (E+G+J+L==26)
- (H+I+J+K==26)
- (A+B+E+H+K+L==26)

So I started programming a program that would loop through all options brute forcing a solution. The loop is working, however, it now shows solutions where one number is used more than once, which is not allowed. How can I make it in the code that it also checks whether all variables are different or not?

```
if ((A!= B != C != D != E != F != G != H != I != J != K != L)
```

I tried the above, but it doesn't work, because it says:

> incomparable types: boolean and int.

**How can I make a check within 1 or a small statement for whether or not all the numbers are different?**

(instead of making a nested 12*12 statement which checks every variable combination)

This is my code so far:

```
    public class code {
   public static void main(String[] args){

    for(int A = 1; A < 13; A++){
     for(int B = 1; B < 13; B++){
      for(int C = 1; C < 13; C++){
       for(int D = 1; D < 13; D++){
        for(int E = 1; E < 13; E++){
         for(int F = 1; F < 13; F++){
          for(int G = 1; G < 13; G++){
           for(int H = 1; H < 13; H++){
            for(int I = 1; I < 13; I++){
             for(int J = 1; J < 13; J++){
              for(int K = 1; K < 13; K++){
               for(int L = 1; L < 13; L++){
                if ((A+C+F+H==26) && (A+D+G+K==26) && (B+C+D+E==26) && (B+F+I+L==26) && (E+G+J+L==26) && (H+I+J+K==26) && (A+B+E+H+K+L==26)){
                 if ((A= C != D != E != F != G != H != I != J != K != L)){
                 System.out.println("A: " + A);
                 System.out.println("B: " + B);
                 System.out.println("C: " + C);
                 System.out.println("D: " + D);
                 System.out.println("E: " + E);
                 System.out.println("F: " + F);
                 System.out.println("G: " + G);
                 System.out.println("H: " + H);
                 System.out.println("I: " + I);
                 System.out.println("J: " + J);
                 System.out.println("K: " + K);
                 System.out.println("L: " + L);
                 }
                }
               }
              }
             }
            }
           }
          }
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }

}
```

Comment: +1. This is an example of what a homework question *should* be like. :)

Comment: Off-topic, but just note that in Java, the convention is to capitalize the first letter of class names. So it's better to name your class `Code` instead of `code`. The file name should also be changed to `Code.java` from `code.java`. A more meaningful name is even better, something like `SixPointedStarProblemSolver`.

Comment: @ adam: thanks, I put some work in before asking over here :) @bytecode: Thanks for the comment, but it is for personal use only, I think my teacher doesnt want me brute forcing it, but doing it another way I have no clue how to do it :)

Comment: Another advice: Read Effective Java whenever you have some free time. It's a great companion for learning Java. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/

Comment: You can use these terms '(A+C+F+H==26) (A+D+G+K==26) (B+C+D+E==26) (B+F+I+L==26) (E+G+J+L==26) (H+I+J+K==26) (A+B+E+H+K+L==26)' and simplify them by deduction. Those variables are not independent so you can reduce the amount of tries in bruteforcing. E.g: `A=26-C-F-H`. Now you can substitute all occurences of `A` in the other terms with `26-C-F-H`. Proceed with other variables also. You have 7 terms and 12 variables, so I guess you can eliminate some variables. In the end you have less variables to iterate through, eg generate Permutations of `1,..,12'

Comment: @Javaaaa If one was running some kind of algorithm on this, I'd imagine (really hope!) that A...L are already a list of sorts (they could be the 'indices'). I couldn't imagine dealing with it otherwise. The code in your question irks me because it seems like lots of extra work is being done. What you are really doing is just finding all the permutations (good keyword) of said list. Or better, see Michaels comment :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested loops will execute `12^12 = 8.91610045E12` IF-Statements, many of them invalid because of wrong combinations of numbers. You need [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of `1,2,3,..,12` as candidates of your bruteforcing approach. The number of permutations of 12 Elements is `12!= 479 001 600`, so the bruteforcing will be much faster I guess. With only generating valid permutations you don't need any check for valid combinations.

Here is some sample code, the code in nextPerm() is copied and modified from [Permutation Generator](http://www.merriampark.com/perm.htm) :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Graph26 {
    private static final int A = 0;
    private static final int B = 1;
    private static final int C = 2;
    private static final int D = 3;
    private static final int E = 4;
    private static final int F = 5;
    private static final int G = 6;
    private static final int H = 7;
    private static final int I = 8;
    private static final int J = 9;
    private static final int K = 10;
    private static final int L = 11;

    private final static boolean rule1(final int[] n) {
        return n[A] + n[C] + n[F] + n[H] == 26;
    }

    private final static boolean rule2(final int[] n) {
        return n[A] + n[D] + n[G] + n[K] == 26;
    }

    private final static boolean rule3(final int[] n) {
        return n[H] + n[I] + n[J] + n[K] == 26;
    }

    private final static boolean rule4(final int[] n) {
        return n[B] + n[C] + n[D] + n[E] == 26;
    }

    private final static boolean rule5(final int[] n) {
        return n[B] + n[F] + n[I] + n[L] == 26;
    }

    private final static boolean rule6(final int[] n) {
        return n[E] + n[G] + n[J] + n[L] == 26;
    }

    private final static boolean rule7(final int[] n) {
        return n[A] + n[B] + n[E] + n[H] + n[K] + n[L] == 26;
    }

    private final static boolean isValid(final int[] nodes) {
        return rule1(nodes) && rule2(nodes) && rule3(nodes) && rule4(nodes)
                && rule5(nodes) && rule6(nodes) && rule7(nodes);
    }

    class Permutation {
        private final int[] o;
        private boolean perms = true;

        public boolean hasPerms() {
            return perms;
        }

        Permutation(final int[] obj) {
            o = obj.clone();
        }

        private int[] nextPerm() {
            int temp;
            int j = o.length - 2;
            while (o[j] > o[j + 1]) {
            j--;
            if (j < 0) {
            perms = false;
            break;
            }
            }
            if (perms) {
            int k = o.length - 1;
            while (o[j] > o[k]) {
            k--;
            }
            temp = o[k];
            o[k] = o[j];
            o[j] = temp;
            int r = o.length - 1;
            int s = j + 1;
            while (r > s) {
            temp = o[s];
            o[s] = o[r];
            o[r] = temp;
            r--;
            s++;
            }
            }
            return o.clone();
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        int[] nodes = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
        final Graph26 graph = new Graph26();
        final Permutation p = graph.new Permutation(nodes);
        int i = 0;
        while (p.hasPerms()) {
        if (isValid(nodes)) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nodes));
        }
        i++;
        nodes = p.nextPerm();
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow man! After some minor code changes after compiling errors occured this really worked fast. Where my programm ran for 12 hours straight on my computer to find all, this found it in a minute or so. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome! As a challenge, you can reduce the rules to check as mentioned in my comment to your question. This would fasten the program even more.

Answer (score 11):

If I get it correctly, you want to check if all A to L are unique. So just put them in a set and find the size of the set:

```
if ((new HashSet<Integer>(
        Arrays.asList(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L)))
    .size() == 12) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: @Javaaaa If one was running some kind of algorithm on this, I'd imagine (really hope!) that A...L are *already* a list of sorts (they could be the 'indices'). I couldn't imagine dealing with it otherwise. The code in your question irks me because it seems like lots of extra work is being done. What you are really doing is just finding all the permutations (good keyword) of said list. Anyway, see Michael's comment in the main post.

Answer (score 5):

I strongly advise using recursion instead, which would vastly simplify the code. Do something like this:

```
function generate(set used, array list):
  if list.size() == 12:
    if list matches criteria:
      yield list as solution
  else:
    for next = 1; next < 13; next++:
      if next not in used:
        used.add(next)
        generate(used, list + next)
        used.remove(next)
```

However, to answer you question directly: You can throw all the values into a [set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and check that it's size is equal to the number of items you threw in. This works because a set will count duplicates as one.

Answer (score 2):

Before looking for a good solution for you, I would like to help with the error you get.

`if ((A= C != D != E != F != G != H != I != J != K != L)){`

This line does not makes much sense. The first thing the compiler will check is:

`if (A=C)`

You probably wanted to code `if (A!=C)`, but let's consider what you really type. `A=C` is an attribution, so `A` will receive `C` value.

Then, the compiler will go on. After attributing `C`'s value to `A`, it will check the comparison:

`if (A=C != D)`

This will compare `A`'s value to `D`, which will result in a boolean -- let's say that the result is `false`.

The next comparison would be:

`if (false != E)`

At this point, there is a comparison between a boolean and an int, hence the error `incomparable types: boolean and int.`.

Well, as you need to check wheter your numbers are unique, a nice solution would be the one proposed by **@abhin4v**.